# How can I sync the computer's clock upon startup?

Tags: windows, datetime, batch-file

I have several servers hosted with GoGrid, and every time I reboot one of my cloud servers, the system clock is incorrect. The server isn't a member of a domain, so I just have the OS set to sync with an Internet time server. This only happens once a day, and I don't see an option to make this happen automatically upon reboot. So I'm left with writing some code to do it for me.

I created a batch file with the "w32tm /resync" command, and scheduled it to run on system startup, but it doesn't work because the network connection isn't available when the batch file is run. How can I cause the time sync to start after the OS is fully loaded and the network connection is available? I need the time to be correct ASAP after the computer boots so timestamps in my database will be correct.

Comment: autoexec.bat :) (won't work on recent windows versions)

Comment: It is, actually. If you look at his answer, he's trying to figure out how to write a batch file to do it.

Comment: Related:  http://superuser.com/questions/529367/automatically-sync-windows-time-more-often-than-default

Comment: `w32tm /resync` command works if computer joined to domain. You can use `net time /domain` command instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On Windows 2008, there is an option in the Task Scheduler that will allow you to wait until a network connection is available before the task is run. In the task properties dialog, create a new "At Startup" trigger, and be sure to check the "Enabled" box. Add an action to run your batch file. Finally, add a Condition to start the task only if the network connection is available. I then asked it to restart the command up to 3 times if it failed. That seems to work great.

On older versions of Windows, use the following batch file contents to retry the sync command until it is successful, or until it has retried too many times.

```
REM *** Retry for up to 15 minutes (90 retries @ 10 seconds each)
set retryCount=0

:SyncStart
if %retryCount == 90 goto SyncEnd
set /A retryCount=retryCount + 1

REM *** Resync the system clock
w32tm /resync
if errorlevel 1 goto SyncDelay
if errorlevel 0 goto SyncEnd

:SyncDelay
REM *** If unsuccessful, delay 10 seconds, then retry
choice /n /t:y,10>nul
goto SyncStart

:SyncEnd
```

Comment: `choice` for Win 10 has invalid syntax. As @scrappylaptop said, for Win 7+ use `choice /N /T 10 /D y>nul`

Comment: For Windows 8, I'm using the Task Scheduler configured as described, with the command ”w32tm /resync". I had to configure the Windows Time seevice as ”Automatic (delayed)" startup because the w32tm command fails if the service is disabled.

Answer (score 174):

In Windows 10, I went to services and enabled "Windows Time" service `w32time` to be automatic, that solved it for me.

My issue occured because I have a dual boot with Linux and for some reason Windows's clock is always off after I boot in Linux.

Comment: dualbooting hackintosh and everytime after i boot macOS, windows clock is broken. this fixed it for me too

Comment: I also have a dual boot machine with this issue, thanks! I know why this happens (Linux expects hardware clock to be UTC, Windows expects local time) but wasn't sure how to automate clock sync on Windows at startup, so your answer was helpful.

Comment: FYI Linux/MacOS/*nixes store the UTC time in the hardware clock, Windows store the local time. Hence the discrepency.

Comment: Time still doesnt sync when windows boots up.  Service shows as "Automatic (Trigger Start).  ANy way to remove the trigger?

Comment: This works great the first time, but you need something more to make it happen with every boot.  Create a task to run at boot time with highest privileges to run w32tm /resync

Comment: doesn't seem to work on windows 11

Answer (score 42):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128248/2265240) this may be related to having a dual boot system with windows 10 and linux.

In my case the service was set to be run only manually and therefore was never triggered as one would suspect. Adjusting the service to be run automatically on startup within the services administration of windows solved the issue for me.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Normally the Windows Time Service should take care of this for you.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773013.aspx

Do you have the service running?

Comment: I think that this page: [Configuring Systems for High Accuracy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/configuring-systems-for-high-accuracy) is more useful on how to setup the service.

Comment: in Windows 10 this service is "manual" booting by default, o putting in "Automatic" solves the issue as other answers expose

Answer (score 5):

Open a **terminal (as Admin)** and run this command:

Use this on your home computer or not joined to domain
`w32tm /resync`

Use this if you are joined to domain
`net time /domain`

If you get a The service has not been started. (0x80070426) error, then it means that you need to start the Windows Time service, wait a minute, and try again.

If you get a The computer did not resync because no time data was available error, then you should be able to try again until successful.

[Windows 10: Synchronize Clock with an Internet Time Server in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6410-synchronize-clock-internet-time-server-windows-10-a.html#option2)

Comment: but the question requests to do it on reboot

Comment: @logoff put it on a bash script on startup and... Voilà

Answer (score 3):

Use task scheduler to create a basic task.  Run with highest privileges at System Startup.  Start program c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe then set the optional arguments to /C w32tm /resync

The Windows Time service must also be running, so set that to automatic as mentioned in some of the other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

scheduled task that runs on login maybe?

EDIT: you may want to put a 30 second or so hold in the script to allow for the network connections to refresh.  Totally didn't read your question right.

Answer (score 1):

i try w32sync with option automatic (delayed start) and that is solved for me ....

Answer (score 1):

I use this batch script for resync Windows time: *Must be run as administrator*

```
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
w32tm /resync
```

Comment: I created a shortcut that marked as "run as administrator"

Answer (score 0):

In my Case with dual windows/linux boot, time wasn't getting synced on Windows,
Even when "Windows Time" was set to "Automatic".
Changing it to "Automatic (Delayed Start)" fixed it for me -
The time gets synced about 1 minute after Windows starts.

Answer (score -1):

I should have realized that I needed to run this batch file as an administrator for it to work, but once I figured that out, I only had to make a minor adjustment to the choice command for it to work like a charm.

```
choice /n /t:10 /D:y
```

Like the above user, I too have a dual boot between Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 7, where booting to Ubuntu set's the System Clock to UTC and the OS adjusts for GMT, whereas it looks like Windozz sets the system clock to the time zone.

Setting to the task scheduler was easy enough, my only specific issue is that I have my laptop connect to my FritzBox for time, so I guess my updates will only happen when I'm at home.
(Its' easy enough to swap the NTP back to one of the presets, so I'm not concerned)

Answer (score -2):

Found this semi-randomly. New choice.exe syntax for Win 7+ to insert a 10-second pause

```
choice /N /T 10 /D y>nul
```